# I cannot get NSUserDefaults to work, tried all i know, anyone had same issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I can't get `NSUserDefaults` to save a `BOOL` value. It's really simple and people do it but it just simply will not save. I tried everything I know. The most recent attempt being this:

```
if (_EndHide == YES) {
     NSDictionary *aProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]forKey:@"EndHide"];
     BOOL boolValue;
     if ([aProperties valueForKey:@"EndHide"])
         boolValue = [[aProperties valueForKey:@"EndHide"] boolValue];
} else if (_EndHide == NO) {
     NSDictionary *aProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]forKey:@"EndHide"];

     BOOL boolValue;
     if ([aProperties valueForKey:@"EndHide"])
         boolValue = [[aProperties valueForKey:@"EndHide"] boolValue];
}
```

What happens is I am making an iOS app game for iPhone and when you dodged these well objects for period of time, you end the game and unlock a button on the start menu named endless, after the story.

Now I need this button to be constantly unlocked. I managed to unlock it through a scene. It's all working but it just won't stay unlocked. Does anyone have any advice to help me with this?

Here is the endless button configuration and bool configuration:

```
 @property(nonatomic, getter=isActive) bool EndHide;

 @property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *endless;
```

That's all the code for the buttons and bools anyway to keep it unlocked.

I know it's simple but it won't work. Maybe a deep bug I tried it on another more updated version of Xcode but still to no avail. The issue is persistent and a real problem. I even tried switch saving that didnt work as well.

Comment: Read [ask]. Your title is very uninformative to say the least. Also use proper formatting and capitalization.

Comment: You are declaring `boolValue` within the scope of the `if`/`else` clauses and their value will be lost as soon as that scope completes. Your code can be reduced to `BOOL boolValue = _EndHide;`.

Comment: Your question doesn't use user defaults and tries to access the dictionary using KVC...

Comment: granted i know little of the code above, but it was last resort attempt and it failed :( i might have to learn core data and try that.

Comment: Learn core data?  I think that would be running before you can walk.

Comment: i know what it is, but not much else i can do

Comment: fixed it read comment below!! cant mark it as answer o.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching, I found it. What happens is, instead of keep the bool changed aka always YES i just saved another bool with this: 
in view did load top part:

```
  if (_EndHide == YES) {
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"boolSet"];


   } else if (_EndHide == NO) { }
```

so when the bool is yes you finished the game than this code: 
in view did load top: 
bottom:

```
   if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"boolSet"]) {
     NSLog(@"not workin -.-");
    } else {
       NSLog(@"finallyyyy workin !! YAeh");
       _endless.hidden = NO;
   }
```

code simply always remembers :D thank you everyone for trying to help me this method was best, endless is a button, create another bool that save in memory use it to unlock the button.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot actually see any code that tries to save anything to the user defaults. You first need to get the user defaults object

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

To write a bool value:

```
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"EndHide"];
```

To read a bool value:

```
BOOL boolValue = [defaults boolForKey:@"EndHide"];
```

Fix any mistakes that I may have made yourself.

PS. Do NOT use valueForKey unless you really understand what it does. Use objectForKey or array syntax.

Comment: Hi, sorry what you saw up there was a last resort attempt to get it to work, i used your code as following, in the view did load the the code gets loaded:  NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     BOOL boolValue = [defaults boolForKey:@"EndHide"]; as such at this point its nil, after i finish the game, and all is showing and the save code is ran:  NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"EndHide"]; after the button appears but it sadly still fails to save, i have indeed tried this but just not working

Answer (score -1):

try this in the view did load

```
NSUserDefaults* prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:@"0" forKey:@"test"];
NSString * testValue = [prefs ObjectforKey:@"test"];
NSLog(testValue);
```

can you please tell me what is the console printing out?